ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here error inside outer Select
I have the below query that I have added a ROW_NUMBER PARTITION BY window function that I have wrapped inside an outer SELECT statement.
I am getting an error

ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here

This is my SQL code:
 (SELECT * FROM 
         (SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                 ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                 TO_CHAR(MAX(B.COST_DATE)) COST_DATE,                             
                 to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST
                 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE ORDER BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, B.COST_DATE DESC) rownum1
                      FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
                           CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
                           CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                     WHERE 1=1
                       AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
                       AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID
                   
                       AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                       AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                       AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID                      
                             
                       AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID                        
               GROUP BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                   ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE                             
                   ,to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90')
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE ORDER BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, B.COST_DATE DESC )
                        
    ORDER BY COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
    ) 
    WHERE rownum1 = 1  AND TRANSACTION_COST IS NOT NULL )


It's not the outer query, it's referring to it in a group-by clause; but why do you have that clause at all? Should your MAX() also be the analytic version, not the aggregate version?

I want to essentially get the max dated (COST_DATE) record by INVENTORY_ITEM_ID and SUBINVENTORY_CODE. Can I change something related to the MAX() to accomplish that?

You probably don't want the MAX() or GROUP BY at all then, and possibly INVENTORY_ITEM_ID should be in the PARTITION not the ORDER BY... It would be easier to understand and make suggestions if you could provide a [mre].

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate what you're trying to do.  See also; Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

The syntax error is that the analytic/windowed function works across the  rows returned to the SELECT block, but those returned rows are not known until after the aggregation / GROUP BY.  So, you can't use ROW_NUMBER() in the GROUP BY block, and we need to know what you're trying to do in order to tell you how to fix the query.

Going by your comment that max dated COST_DATE is required by INVENTORY_ITEM_ID and SUBINVENTORY_CODE, INVENTORY_ITEM_ID can be included in the PARTITION BY clause and ROW_NUMBER removed from the GROUP BY clause.
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
        C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
        TO_CHAR(MAX(B.COST_DATE)) COST_DATE,
        TO_CHAR(MAX(B.TRANSACTION_COST), 'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC) AS rownum1
    FROM 
        CST_ONHAND_V A
    INNER JOIN CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B ON A.REC_TRXN_ID = B.TRANSACTION_ID
                                        AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                                        AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                                        AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
    INNER JOIN CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C ON A.REC_TRXN_ID = C.REC_TRXN_ID
    WHERE A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
    GROUP BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE
    ORDER BY COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
)
WHERE rownum1 = 1 AND TRANSACTION_COST IS NOT NULL;

